# Jpa2 Implementation testing

Tags: testing, jpa, jpa-2.1

I would like to test some JPA code with different implementations like Hibernate,EclipseLink,OpenJPA.

I am still looking for am elegant way of doing this but did not found one yet.

However I wonder that the implementors do not have some kind of tests that they need to execute in order to prove that their implementation is compliant with the specific standard (JPA2.1)

Do you know if there is a test compatibility kit like for JPA so i can inspire myself from there ?

Any suggestion of how i would run the tests easily switching  between implementations is welcome.

I thought on using maven profiles...but running main classes might be not so nice.

Thanks

Comment: There is a JPA TCK. It's secret; go figure. Oracle won't share it with the world, so you've no real idea how well implementations meet the spec other than doing your own testing.

Comment: I see....what about doing one that might be open source...done by hibernate,openjpa, you ,maybe eclipse link....cause i guess everybody is kind of reinventing the wheel so the effort now is multiplied compared to a common solution

Comment: I would gladly contribute